# make rare game of

Tags: meaning

It's a part of fairy tale 'The Giant's Heart' by George MacDonald.

As soon as he began (to sing), other bird replied, making rare game of him.

what's the meaning of 'rare game' in this sentence ?

Comment: This should be General Reference for anyone who wants to read fairy tales written over 150 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

In this context "rare game" means unusually great sport. Mammals and birds hunted for sport are referred to as game. The other birds reply to Owl's song with scorn and mockery, which they consider sport.

Answer (score 1):

*[to make game of](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/game) (somebody)*; to make fun of; ridicule: to make game of the weak and defenseless.

The use of the adjective, rare, suggests that it was not often that the birds had the courage or audacity to tease the owl who was singing.

> All at once an owl began to hoot. He thought he was singing. As soon
>   as he began, other birds replied, making rare game of him. To their
>   astonishment, the children found they could understand every word they
>   sang. [source](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/5910/)